# DateTime picker with vue-ctk-date-time-picker

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, datetimepicker

I have been trying t figure this out for the pas 6 hours. Can someone please help me.

I used this DateTime picker vue-ctk-date-time-picker
Link to gitRepo https://github.com/chronotruck/vue-ctk-date-time-picker

My startdate looks like this in my vue data start: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")

example: 2020-06-28 19:30

Now the date picker works fine and starts at that date and time. Perfect!

I want to add a maxDate to the dateTimePicker so people cant select a date and time higher than the current date. So i made another property in data like this

maxDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")

Which is again just the datetime now.

As soon as i add the prop :maxDate='maxdate' on the date picker it keeps the date but the time goes to 00:00

Does not matter what format i make it and also does not matter if i use moment or not. maxDate prop changes my start date time to 00:00 and maxdate to 00:00.

If i do minDate with the exact same props and data then minDate work as expected. Time is correct date is correct.

Switch it back to maxDate and BOOOM! freakin 00:00 again

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do i need NUXT? for this thing to work

Answer (score 0):

So figured it out. Max date should just be the date in date format without time.

maxDate =  moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")

and not

maxDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")

Comment: Well still down not work because it does not disable the time then. Just the date, and as soon as you add the time the it goes back to 00:00